# How do I cancel a heavy assault order?

Tags: floor-13

I ordered an assault to a specific location just like any other assault order. But in this case, I'm pretty sure is what causing the visit of Mr. Garcia.

How do I cancel an order?

I already tried checking the assault options and there is nothing [in the manual](http://www.lemonamiga.com/games/docs.php?id=667).